# How to deploy existing REST service with Geoserver

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee, geoserver

In short, I want to add Geoserver extension with its own REST service (independent from the default Geoserver REST service).

How would you approach this problem? Should I add REST-starting servlets from the external webapp to the Geoserver sources? If yes, where should I copy them and where should I use them?

I am trying to deploy my own REST service (working fine in external Spring webapp) using Geoserver, so the webapp would become obsolete and the new REST service would be visible in `geoserver/rest2` path. Both Geoserver, all its services and new REST would have access to the same Geoserver user context. 
I am trying to achieve this by adding new path-to-class mapping in `applicationContext.xml` in `src/gs-restConfig` and `src/gs-rest`, but starting my own REST service using Geoserver is still unsolved. 
Or maybe am I trying to achieve something odd and nonsensical?

Comment: You can simply deploy the GeoServer war file to your JavaEE application server together with your own war file, containing your REST service. I would suggest to use your own path for your REST service e.g. `my-app/resources` instead of messing with the GeoServer namespace.

Comment: Thank you, it's possible that your proposed solution may be the only way to achieve my goal. I am trying nonetheless to merge both applications and deploy them as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have achieved my goal by adding my own REST service to the geoserver/src/web/app project. Maybe it's a bit extreme, but it serves my goals ;) 
Mainly it required adding the external (my own) REST service and related classed to the Geoserver `web.xml` and `applicationContext.xml` files. When Geoserver is started this service coexits with Geoserver and is accessed in its path (Geoserver/rest2).